# Postfix- open relay. How to configure so it is not?

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp, spam

I have setup Postfix but am having trouble with the setup.

Whenever I used to send emails to the server, it reject my mails saying 'Relaying Denied', so I changed the following in `main.cf`:

```
mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0
mynetworks_style = subnet
```

I can now send email and it works, but MX tests say that it is an open relay (obviously unintended).

How can I resolve this? I obviously want anybody to be able to email my domain, but I'm unsure of the configuration.

I know I can change the `mynetworks`, but then doesn't this restrict who CAN email to the server?

Comment: Are you trying to *relay* mail through this server, or to *deliver* mail to this server?

Comment: Makes no difference with respect to this issue, since an open relay is an open relay. Email is not a trivial undertaking.

Answer (score 6):

The problem that opens you up is the

```
mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0
```

Cause somewhere below you probably have it listed in

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = ... permit_mynetworks ...
```

If you need to be able to send email from any ip then you just look at enabled a user/password to send email which the common one is sasl

Answer (score 5):

mynetworks must only contain trusted users that can use the server to relay mails to other domains - otherwise, as you've found, it's an open relay. You might want to set it to 192.168.0.0/16, 10/8 or 172.16.0.0/12 if using RFC 1918 addresses on your internal network.

The settings that control whether people can send mail to your server include mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains - read the docs [here](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) or [here](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html).

Comment: mydestination, relay_domains, and virtual_[alias|mailbox]_maps. NOT virtual_[alias|mailbox]_DOMAINS.

Answer (score 3):

As documented at http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks :

> mynetworks (default: see "postconf -d" output)
>   The list of "trusted" remote SMTP clients that have more privileges than "strangers".
>
> **In particular, "trusted" SMTP clients are allowed to relay mail
>   through Postfix.**
>   See the smtpd_recipient_restrictions parameter description in the postconf(5) manual.

Answer (score 0):

use authentification only for yours ip:
main.cf

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    reject_unauth_destination
```

use file to store your ip main.cf:

```
mynetworks = hash:/etc/postfix/network_table
```

Use script to update your ip if change (run in cron)

```
#!/bin/bash
###
## sh /sx_sys/postfix_mynetwork_ip_checker.sh
LOGFILE="/var/log/smtp_relay.log"

curent_ip=$(dig @exemple.com exemple.com | awk '/^;; ANSWER SECTION:$/ { getline ; print $5 }')
#echo $curent_ip

saved_ip=$(</etc/postfix/network_table )
#echo $saved_ip
if [ "$curent_ip OK" != "$saved_ip" && -n "$curent_ip"]; then
echo "$curent_ip OK" > "/etc/postfix/network_table"
postmap /etc/postfix/network_table
echo "$(date) smtp allow for $curent_ip" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
mail -s "smtp allow for $curent_ip $(date)" s2@myserv.exemple.com < /dev/null
fi
exit 0
```