# My Postfix sending out spam

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix

I checked my etc/log/mail.log and i find huge file that contain a lot of rows like those (every sec insert 20 rows):

```
Jan 31 06:25:20 myservername postfix/smtp[15459]: 02ACF5FBC3: to=<xxxx@yahoo.com>, relay=mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[98.137.159.28]:25, delay=412553, delays=412501/50/1.6/0.13, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (host mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[98.137.159.28] said: 421 4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from myServerIP temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://help.yahoo.com/kb/post$
Jan 31 06:25:20 myservername postfix/smtp[15459]: 02ACF5FBC3: to=<xxxxxx@yahoo.com>, relay=mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[98.137.159.28]:25, delay=412553, delays=412501/50/1.6/0.13, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (host mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[98.137.159.28] said: 421 4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from myServerIP temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaste$
Jan 31 06:25:20 myservername postfix/smtp[15463]: 08B5359448: host mta6.am0.yahoodns.net[98.137.159.28] said: 421 4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from myServerIP temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/SLN3434.html (in reply to MAIL FROM command)
Jan 31 06:25:20 myservername postfix/smtp[15463]: 08B5359448: lost connection with mta6.am0.yahoodns.net[98.137.159.28] while sending RCPT TO
Jan 31 06:25:20 myservername postfix/smtp[15464]: 680715EDFD: host smtp5.opco.com[208.88.204.132] refused to talk to me: 554 5.7.1 You are not allowed to connect.
Jan 31 06:25:20 myservername postfix/smtp[15453]: 97AEE58388: host mx142.netapp.com[216.240.21.19] refused to talk to me: 554 mx142.netapp.com
```

- I never sent those mails.
- Is it possible that my server hacked?
- How can I set that only my server(ip) can send mail?
- I have checked my php files and close any possible trigger mail function.
- I need my server that could send and receive mail.

main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = MYDOMAIN.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost $mydomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

virtual_alias_domains = yooteam.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
compatibility_level = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

*I don't have the reputation to comment so I will put it here.*

You likely have an open mail relay setup which means anyone can use your server to send mail: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay

[Postfix- open relay. How to configure so it is not?](https://serverfault.com/questions/422468/postfix-open-relay-how-to-configure-so-it-is-not/612797)